# Access granted not appearing on third attempt

Tags: python-3.x

on the final attempt, if the right password is entered, the "access granted" print does not appear before program exits

```
AccessGranted = False
attempt = 1
password = input("Please enter your password: ")
while (attempt < 3) and (AccessGranted == False):
           if password == "compScience":
                      AccessGranted = True
                      print("Access granted")

           else:
                      password = input("Incorrect password -  re-enter: ")
                      attempt = attempt +1
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the third attempt of input inside the else statement, `attempt` is equals to 3 and then the loop is ended (you should not place the input inside the else). That's why the program exits and does not show anything. If you want just 3 attempts, I think the following code is better:

```
AccessGranted = False
attempt = 1
while (attempt < 4) and (AccessGranted == False):
    password = input("Password: ")
    if password == "compScience":
        AccessGranted = True
        print("Access granted")
    else:
        print("Incorrect password. ")
        attempt = attempt + 1
```

You can see that I placed the input inside the while-loop, and the condition to stop became `attempt < 4`, in order to allow 3 attempts.